# How to write a Linq to Entities query given a list of entities as parameter

Tags: .net, linq, entities

I have 2 tables: `Materials` and `Colors` with two colums

```
Materials (guid and name)
Colors (guid and name)
```

One Material can have a lot of colors  and a Color can be in a lot of Materials. (many to many relationship)

Using LINQ I can write `Material.colors` and this send me a list of the entities of color contained in that material.

I would like to make function in which I pass a list of `Color` and return what materials have those Colors.

I am writing in VB.net

```
Public Shared Function getMaterialsFromColor(vColors As List(Of Entities.Color)) As List(Of Entities.Materials)

    Dim _materials As New List(Of Entities.Materials)

    _materials.AddRange(From vmaterial as Entities.Materials where vmaterial.color.name=)

    '(this is the part that I dont know)
end function
```

thanks a lot

I am using sqlserver express and linq to entities (ado.net)

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: Please re-write your question and code to be at least consistent if not correct and compilable.

Comment: Not familiar with VB.NET, but you need `Contains`. `where vColors.Contains(vmaterial.color)`